# Python Request Module - Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to import the requests module for my app which I want to view locally on Google App Engine. I am getting a log console error telling me that "no such module exists".

I've installed it in the command line (using `pip`) and even tried to install it in my project directory. When I do that the shell tells me:

> "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages".

App Engine is telling me that the module doesn't exist and the shell says it's already installed it.

I don't know if this is a path problem. If so, the only App Engine related application I can find in my mac is the launcher?

Comment: You could use python's httplib module instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put the requests module i.e. [the contents of the requests folder](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tree/master/requests)  within your project directory. Just for the sake of clarity, your app directory should look like

```
/myapp/app.yaml
/myapp/main.py
/myapp/requests/packages/
/myapp/requests/__init__.py
/myapp/requests/adapters.py
etc...
```

then within main.py put something like

```
import webapp2
import requests

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        g = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
        self.response.write(g.text)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the basic question (I haven't been at this very long) but how do I do that from Git? There are so many files I don't know what to use.

Comment: @RadhaKapoor you have to actually copy it into the folder directly.

Comment: @RadhaKapoor it's probably simpler to just download the requests library from https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/archive/master.zip unzip it and stick the requests directory into your appengine folder.

Comment: @user714852 so I literally just dragged and dropped the entire requests folder you linked to into my web app project folder. I'm still getting the same error ie "no module named requests". Did I put it in the wrong folder - did you mean something different? Thank you again - I really appreciate it.

Comment: have you put "import requests" before you call the library?

Comment: in main.py i have included the following at the top of the file:                           **from google.appengine.ext import db,

import webapp2,
import os,
import jinja2,
import requests, 
import json,
import logging**

Comment: I've put in some detail in the answer above which should solve your problem hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the requests/requests sub-folder to your project. From your script's location (`.`), you should see a file at `./requests/__init__.py`.

This applies to all modules you include for Google App Engine. If it doesn't have a `__init__.py` directly under that location, it will not work.

You do not need to add the module to `app.yaml`.