# How to send an image from a telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have my bot working by now, but the thing is it can only send text. I have seen in the Bot API there are functions to send photos, videos... but I can't get it to work. Someone has achieved it? I'm using python source code from [yukuku/telebot](https://github.com/yukuku/telebot)

```
 elif text == '/image':
            img = Image.new('RGB', (512, 512))
            base = random.randint(0, 16777216)
            pixels = [base+i*j for i in range(512) for j in range(512)]  # generate sample image
            img.putdata(pixels)
            output = StringIO.StringIO()
            img.save(output, 'JPEG')
            reply(img=output.getvalue())
```

When I change the code, nothing happened.

```
img = Image.open('image.png')
img.show()
```

Please help me. I need the correct code. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: "change the code"... meaning what? Which **specific** lines of the above did you replace with the below? All of them? Just a few? Also, consider providing a MCVE (per http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- a **verifiable**, **complete** minimal reproducer. Also, what does "nothing happened" mean? No change from stock behavior? No response sent at all?

Comment: I am bad in English
And I want to send images to users when they give me the name
For example
Sends word dog
Bot sends a picture of a dog
can you help me

Comment: Fix the problems in your post, as identified above. Pointing those problems out so you can correct them is *how* I'm attempting to help you.

Comment: I want to make my bot like this bot 
https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=@ImageBot

Comment: how can change this code 
elif text == '/image':
            img = Image.new('RGB', (512, 512))
            base = random.randint(0, 16777216)
            pixels = [base+i*j for i in range(512) for j in range(512)]  # generate sample image
            img.putdata(pixels)
            output = StringIO.StringIO()
            img.save(output, 'JPEG')
            reply(img=output.getvalue())

to send image like this 
http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg

Comment: Edit your question to address the questions I asked in my first comment.

Comment: I have tried to change the text I hope understand me

Comment: The new text still does not answer the questions asked. The concerns are around content, not grammar.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not explain more
What is required is that the bot sends images when requested by him and the image is incorrect

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site where you tell us your goal and we write your code for you, so improving explanation of your goal without resolving other deficiencies is of no help. Go back and reread my first comment, and address what it asks -- **not** simply improving the grammar around your statement of your program's intent, but adding additional information to address its questions. Showing only those two lines does not tell us how you integrated them into the rest of the logic, and "does not work with me" does not tell us how it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is

```
elif 'Hi' in text:
reply(img=urllib2.urlopen('img url').read())
```

or

```
if text == 'help':
            reply(img=urllib2.urlopen('img url').read())
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: get the code from here
https://github.com/yukuku/telebot
and reply the msg like this 
reply(img=urllib2.urlopen('img url').read())

Answer (score 8):

I have included two functions, one is good for sending local images, the other one is good for sending remote images.

```
def sendImage():
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<Token>/sendPhoto";
    files = {'photo': open('/path/to/img.jpg', 'rb')}
    data = {'chat_id' : "YOUR_CHAT_ID"}
    r= requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
    print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.content)

def sendImageRemoteFile(img_url):
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<Token>/sendPhoto";
    remote_image = requests.get(img_url)
    photo = io.BytesIO(remote_image.content)
    photo.name = 'img.png'
    files = {'photo': photo}
    data = {'chat_id' : "YOUR_CHAT_ID"}
    r= requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
    print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.content)
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally a solution that works, there are so many answers to this problem that don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Before sending the photo, you have to do `output.seek(0)` to put the cursor back to the beginning of the file, else it will be read as zero

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question. Here's the answer:

```
        def sendImageFromUrl(url):
            #this tweak added if request image failed
            headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'}
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            #response = requests.get(url)
            output = StringIO(response.content)
            img = Image.open(output)
            img.save(output, 'JPEG')
            resp = multipart.post_multipart(BASE_URL + 'sendPhoto', [
                ('chat_id', str(chat_id)),
                ('caption', 'Your Caption'),
            ], [
                ('photo', 'image.jpg', output.getvalue()),
            ])
```

Make sure your server does have python module: requests.

You can download here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests#downloads

And put in your application like this

```
/myapp/app.yaml
/myapp/main.py
/myapp/requests/packages/
/myapp/requests/__init__.py
/myapp/requests/adapters.py
etc...
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17128168/1097372

Put in main.py after line 10

```
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO
```