# Python Telegram Bot - Send Image

Tags: python, image, api, telegram-bot

I'd like to send a Image (via URL or Path), on request.
I use the source [code here.](https://github.com/yukuku/telebot)
The code has already a sample to send an image (via URL or Path), but I don't get it since I'm new to Python.

Here's the sample code snippet:

```
elif text == '/image':        #request
    img = Image.new('RGB', (512, 512))
    base = random.randint(0, 16777216)
    pixels = [base+i*j for i in range(512) for j in range(512)]  # generate sample image
    img.putdata(pixels)
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    img.save(output, 'JPEG')
    reply(img=output.getvalue())
```

Some API infos can be [found here.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message)

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32441772/1097372
I'm also new to python, so maybe someone could improve my code there.

Answer (score 10):

To send a photo from URL:

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo='https://telegram.org/img/t_logo.png')
```

To send a photo from local Drive:

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('tests/test.png', 'rb'))
```

[Here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#working-with-files-and-media) is the reference documentation.

Comment: Oof +1, by far the only clear example that's understandable for python-telegram-bot

Comment: @RaahimFareed glad it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling to connect the `python-telegram-bot` examples with the above advice. Especially, while having `context` and `update`, I couldnt find `chatid` and `bot`. Now, my two cents:

```py
pic=os.path.expanduser("~/a.png")
context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, photo=open(pic,'rb'))
```