# What is the type of sending a Telebot image

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I send such a message with such an "attached image"? This is clearly not a function of `send_photo`, it completely adjusts the width of the message to the length of the image.

I can assume that this is somehow related to parse_mode, but I don't quite understand how to implement it all.

Example of what I should get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WseTU.jpg (Couldn't insert image). What I recently noticed is that if you just insert a link to an image, it will display it in this way. But I need the user not to see the link

I use the telebot library

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326851/python-telegram-bot-send-image

Comment: @azro, "This is clearly not a function of send_photo, it completely adjusts the width of the message to the length of the image."