# How do I send an image using file open with python an telepot?

Tags: telepot

I'm trying to send an image from my drive to telegram using the method sendPhoto but I can't. Which is the trick ?

I'm using Python 3.6.7  My code is as follows:

```
import sys
import telepot
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import os
import time 

bot = telepot.Bot('55615????:AA????)
bot.getMe()
id=32????
bot.sendPhoto(chatId, str(open("th-623777.jpg", os.O_RDONLY)) )
```

Comment: see some code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314526/telegram-bot-telepot-api-is-it-possible-to-send-an-image-directly-from-url-wi but couldn't make it work. Also checked the apy on https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html

Comment: What error are you getting?